# Heroku login success, but then freezes

Tags: windows, git, heroku, git-bash

I am using Git Bash on Windows.

I just verified my Heroku account,
then I open git bash and type:

```
$ heroku login
```

bash responds:

```
heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit:
Opening browser to https://cli-auth.heroku.com/auth/browser/c31ddaf9-7a55-4daf-afad-a0500e924c26
heroku: Waiting for login...
Logging in... done
Logged in as [my mail address]
```

and then, I can type whatever I want, but it does not get and execute the command, behaving like a text editor. Then, when I click on the cross to close it, a [warning message appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooT5i.png), telling that some processes are still going on.

How do I unlock the freezing and go on using Bash?

Comment: Try to install latest heroku cli

Comment: It's already updated, I installed it yesterday.

Comment: Does cli open link in browser to authenticate?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I solved it by hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to break out and chose yes (type `y`).

It turns out that the git bash terminal has the frequent problem of turning "frozen" after you enter a command.
Whenever it happens, you should press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>